# The difference of last rows in table with undefined number of blanks between

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel table:

```
Date       | Value
===========+=======
24.02.2019 |  1350
25.02.2019 |  1120
26.02.2019 |  1200
           |
           |
           |
===========+=======
DIFFERENCE |    80
```

The bottom total row (DIFFERENCE) should calculate the difference between value of last inserted record in table and value of previous record. When I tomorrow insert the new record for 27.02.2019 with value 1300, the bottom row should show difference 100 (1300-1200). There are undefined number of blank rows between last inserted row and bottom total row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `OFFSET` and `INDIRECT` are not necessary here, you can simply use INDEX like this:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$10,COUNTA($B$2:$B$10))-INDEX($B$2:$B$10,COUNTA($B$2:$B$10)-1)
```

Note: `OFFSET` and `INDIRECT` are volatile functions, while `INDEX` is not. Volatile means that if anything changes anywhere in your workbook, than its value has to be recalculated. In case of non-volatile function, however, recalculation is initiated only if its parameters (in this case $B$2:$B$10) change. So, in general my solution is more efficient than the other two posted before.

Comment: This is true, however I based my answer on an unknown number of rows and empty rows, with difference being located in column B. If difference is been located in an absolute cell in column B, you are absolutely right!

Comment: I think we know the number of rows: they end above the "DIFFERENCE" row.

Comment: Like I said, if that's true for OP's situation, then you are absolutely right.

Comment: In fact, another way to write you formula could be `=INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(A:A)-1)-INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(A:A)-2)` :)

Comment: This seems to be the most elegant solution. Concatenating the "B" letter with current row given by ROW() to get the range needed by formula seems to me the dirty way (although it works).

Answer (score 1):

And here is another example

`=INDIRECT("B"&COUNTA(INDIRECT("B1:B"&ROW()-1)))-INDIRECT("B"&COUNTA(INDIRECT("B1:B"&ROW()-1))-1)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, this works, quick and dirty...

```
=OFFSET(B1,LOOKUP(2,1/(B:B<>""),ROW(B:B))-1,,)-OFFSET(B1,LOOKUP(2,1/(B:B<>""),ROW(B:B))-2,,)
```

[image]

If you want the result in the same column, then you will have to control the range B:B...